# Capybara, poltergeistでTimed out waiting for response toエラーが出る。

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

http://ja.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20151205231131&SearchText=bag+mens

を起点に、商品ページのURLリストを取得し、その数を出力します。
たまに、期待した出力である6が出力されるのですが、
下記のようなエラーが出てしまう時があります。エラー8割、正常2割くらいの割合です。
何が原因かがわからず、途方に暮れています。
何かヒントをいただけませんか？

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pstore'
require 'anemone'
require 'open_uri_redirections'
require 'openssl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
#require 'phantomjs'


class Crawl
  def get_html_obj(url)
    Capybara.run_server = false
    Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {js_errors: false})
    end
    session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
    session.visit(url)
    return Nokogiri::HTML.parse(session.html)
  end

  def get_page_list(url)
    url_list = Array.new
    doc = get_html_obj(url)
    doc.css('div[class = "ui-pagination-navi util-left"]>a').each do |page|
      url_list << page.attribute("href").text 
    end
    url_list = url_list.sort_by do |k|
      /(.+)(page=)([\d]+)/ =~ k
      $3.to_i
    end
    return url_list.uniq
  end

  def get_page_list_all(url,n)
    url_list_all = Array.new
    crawl_url = Crawl.new
    last_url = url

    n.times do |n|
      url_list = crawl_url.get_page_list(last_url)
      last_url = url_list.last

      url_list_all.concat(url_list)
    end    
     url_list_all = url_list_all.sort_by do |k|
      /(.+)(page=)([\d]+)/ =~ k
      $3.to_i
    end
    return url_list_all.uniq
  end

  def get_product_list(url)
    url_list = Array.new
    doc = get_html_obj(url)
    doc.css('a[class = "history-item product "]').each do |page|
      url_list << page.attribute("href").text 
    end

    return url_list
  end

  def get_product_list_all(url,n)
    url_list = Array.new
    get_page_list_all(url,n).each do |url_tmp|
      doc = get_html_obj(url_tmp)
      doc.css('a[class = "history-item product "]').each do |page|
        url_list << page.attribute("href").text 
      end
    end
    return url_list
  end


  def get_product_obj(url)
    obj = Crawl.new
    return obj.get_html_obj(url)
  end


  def get_product_objs(url)
    obj = Crawl.new
    products = Array.new
    urls = obj.get_product_list(url)

    urls.each do |url|
      products << obj.get_html_obj(url)
    end
    return products
  end

  def get_product_objs_all(url,n)
    obj = Crawl.new
    products = Array.new
    urls = obj.get_page_list_all(url,n)

    urls.each do |url|
      products << obj.get_html_obj(url)
    end
    return products
  end
end

init_url = "http://ja.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20151205231131&SearchText=bag+mens"

crawl = Crawl.new
puts crawl.get_page_list(init_url).count
```

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/poltergeist-1.8.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:98:in `rescue in send': Timed out waiting for response to {"id":"8482ca9f-6a3d-40d2-b6b7-eb33c8327b41","name":"visit","args":["http://ja.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20151205231131&SearchText=bag+mens"]}. It's possible that this happened because something took a very long time (for example a page load was slow). If so, setting the Poltergeist :timeout option to a higher value will help (see the docs for details). If increasing the timeout does not help, this is probably a bug in Poltergeist - please report it to the issue tracker. (Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError)
  from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/poltergeist-1.8.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:94:in `send'
  from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/poltergeist-1.8.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/server.rb:33:in `send'
  from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/poltergeist-1.8.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:340:in `command'
  from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/poltergeist-1.8.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:34:in `visit'
  from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/poltergeist-1.8.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:95:in `visit'
  from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:232:in `visit'
  from C:/Users/Akinori/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RubyApplication1/lib/main2.rb:20:in `get_html_obj'
  from C:/Users/Akinori/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RubyApplication1/lib/main2.rb:26:in `get_page_list'
  from C:/Users/Akinori/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RubyApplication1/lib/main2.rb:109:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PoltergesitのTimeout問題はこちらのissueでも取り上げられています。

https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/375

上のissueを参考にして、過去にこんなオプションを設定したことがあります。
これで試してみるといかがでしょうか？

```
options = { js_errors: false, timeout: 180, phantomjs_logger: StringIO.new, logger: nil, phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'] }
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

まだ同じエラーが出るようであればtimeout秒数を増やしてみてください。（180でも結構長いと思いますが）

### 追記

実際に動かしてみましたが、特にエラーは出ません。
完了までに10秒弱かかりますが、タイムアウトは発生しませんでした。

ただし、何度か実行しているとそれまで表示されていた「6」が「0」になり、それ以降ずっと「0」が表示されています。
HTMLをputsしたところ、ブラウザの表示とは異なる中国語のHTMLが出力されました。

次に、WebドライバをPhantomJSからSelenium（Firefox）に変更して、30回ほど連続実行したところ、途中から商品ページではなく、ログイン画面が表示されました。(サーバー負荷を考慮し、実行時は1回アクセスするたびに1秒のスリープを挟んでいます)

```
# ...
  def get_html_obj(url)
    Capybara.run_server = false
    session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
    session.visit(url)
    puts session.html
    return Nokogiri::HTML.parse(session.html)
  end
# ...
crawl = Crawl.new
30.times do
  puts crawl.get_page_list(init_url).count
  sleep 1
end
```

推測するに、クローラやスクレイピングを禁止する仕組みがサイトに用意されている気がします。

タイムアウトした理由はよくわかりませんが、このサイトをスクレイピングするのは推奨されていないようなので、諦めた方が良いかもしれません。（スクレイピングを歓迎するサイトの方が珍しいとは思いますが・・・）

### 追記2

> これを防ぐには、proxyでアクセス毎にipアドレスを変えるのと、user agentを変える必要がありますか？ また、ログイン画面が表示されたことを検出し、ログイン処理をcapybaraで行えばいいのでしょうか？

そのあたりまで踏み込んでしまうと、サイトの利用方法的にグレーゾーンに入ってしまいそうなので、回答しかねます。（そもそも僕もよくわかりません）

また、親サイト（？）の[Alibaba.comの利用規約3.2](http://rule.alibaba.com/rule/detail/2041.htm)には「許可なしにロボットによる情報収集を行ってはいけない」というような記述が見られます。

> Systematic retrieval of Site Content from the Sites to create or compile, directly or indirectly, a collection, compilation, database or directory (whether through robots, spiders, automatic devices or manual processes) without written permission from Alibaba.com is prohibited.

なので、最悪の場合、何か問題を起こして訴えられる、ということも起きかねません。（日本国内ですら[こういう事件](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B2%A1%E5%B4%8E%E5%B8%82%E7%AB%8B%E4%B8%AD%E5%A4%AE%E5%9B%B3%E6%9B%B8%E9%A4%A8%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6)が起きてますので）

AliexpressにはどうやらAPIがあるようなので、そちらを利用した方が良いのではないでしょうか。

http://portals.aliexpress.com/help/help_center_API.html

Comment: 教えていただいた設定でやってみましたが、
まだ同じエラーがでてしまいます。

クロールに時間がかかるのは、S/Wの作りがよくないからでしょうか？

Comment: seleniumでhtmlオブジェクトを取得する際、
Firefoxのステータスバーに注目すると、

「～からの応答待ちです」「アドレスの解決をしています」と表示され、Webサイトの表示が遅い(10秒以上かかることも)ことがわかりました。

これが、poltergeistでTimed out waiting for response to
エラーが出る原因ではないかと考え、対策がないかを検索しました。

すると、下記のようなページにたどり着きました。
http://plaza.rakuten.co.jp/mscrtf/diary/201208160000/

こちらに記載のような対策を行ったところ、
seleniumでFirefoxでページを取得するスピードが明らかに上がりました。
しかし、改善した理由がいまひとつわかりません。


Poltergeistでも、
Timed out waiting for response toエラーが出る頻度が下がりました。

正常：異常の割合が、
2:8から9:1くらいになりました。

Comment: ただ、何回も同じページをスクレイピングしていると、ログイン画面に飛ばされてしまいます。これを防ぐには、proxyでアクセス毎にipアドレスを変えるのと、user agentを変える必要がありますか？

また、ログイン画面が表示されたことを検出し、ログイン処理をcapybaraで行えばいいのでしょうか？

初めてscrapingに挑戦しているもので、いとう様の回答に大変助けられています。いつもありがとうございます。

Comment: apiが利用できることは知りませんでした。
しかし、apiで得られる情報には限りがあるのと、apiには利用制限があるので、
できれば、クローリングして情報を得たいのですが、
Alibaba.comがロボットによる情報収集を認めていないのなら、
やめたほうが無難そうですね。。

法律に違反しない範囲内で、いろいろ研究してみます。
ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

何度もアクセスしていると、サーバー側がクローラーだと判断してレスポンスを返さなくなるのかもしれません。

http://ja.aliexpress.com/robots.txt には以下のように書かれており、少なくともBaiduのクローラーに対しては http://ja.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20151205231131&SearchText=bag+mens へのアクセスを禁じているように見えます。

```
# file: robots.txt,v 1.0 2002/09/23 created by Tsing Kong
# www.alibaba.com
# <URL:http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/exclusion.html#robotstxt>
# Format is:
#       User-agent: <name of spider>
#       Disallow: <nothing> | <path>
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /productdetail/

User-agent: Baiduspider
Disallow: /promotion/
Disallow: /wholesale?

User-agent: baiduspider
Disallow: /promotion/
```

Comment: Seiei様の推測は当たっていました。

回避する方法を考えます。
ありがとうございました。